# Mapping complex field of an object to a text field (serialized as JSON) before saving with reactive spring repository

Tags: json, postgresql, spring-data, r2dbc, spring-data-r2dbc

I'm using Spring data r2dbc repositories to save pojo's to Postgres DB. I have a class with complex field `definition`:

```
// Getters and setters omitted for brevity
public class TestType {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private TestDefinition definition;

    public static class TestDefinition {

        private String testField;

    }

}
```

I'm trying to find a way to add a converter which will serialize this complex field to JSON when `ReactiveCrudRepository.save` method is called. I looked at source code and read the API docs but am unable to find a place where my logic could be plugged in.

This was easy to do in projects using `JPA` and `Hibernate` by creating custom `UserType` classes. If anybody has any pointers I'd be much obliged for any assistance.

**Edit**

This is now doable, check out: https://medium.com/@nikola.babic1/mapping-to-json-fields-with-spring-data-r2dbc-and-reactive-postgres-driver-1db765067dc5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Data R2DBC is still young and its feature set grows with every day. Right now, there's no support for custom conversions but you might want to [file a ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc).

PS: Hibernate is around since 2001 (more or less), Spring Data R2DBC was started this year in May.

Comment: Tnx for the info, I ended up using an ugly workaround of having a class which holds JSON in a string field (this class instances get persisted) and they get mapped to other classes when needed in the code.